# Postgres CREATE DATABASE Not Working

Tags: postgresql-12, macos, homebrew

I'm on a `Mac` using `Monterey`.  It's a `Mac M1` which had a bit of an issue using `homebrew` to install `postgres` when I first started working on this machine.  I moved to the `GUI` `postgres.app` which just seemed like a front for the underlying `postgres`, so I didn't think much had changed.

In any case the database (`Postgres 12`) is now running and I am seeing an issue with trying to create a new database.  Same issue in a third party client as well as `psql`.

```
rich=# create database sresearch
rich-# \l
                                   List of databases
     Name     |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
--------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgres     | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 rich         | rich     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 sresearch    | rich     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 template0    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
              |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 weather      | rich     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
(5 rows)

rich-# \c sresearch
FATAL:  no such database: sresearch
```

The database cannot be made for some reason, even though it's reporting having done so.  I have no clue why this is happening, but I want to fix it.

I'm thinking I could make a backup and try to fix this by deleting both versions, then going back to `homebrew` to start again with `Postgres 12`.  I'm not sure how to find out what the difference is between these two slightly different versions, which are essentially the same thing.

How can I fix this?  Obviously I need to be able to make new databases.

Update:  I just reinstalled the `homebrew` version and tried to import my alternative `postgres.app` export.  It hung up on `\connect <dbname>` for some reason but that was easy to manually get around.  This installation **as well** gave me the same error on trying to create a new database.  So both versions are showing the same, even from an export.

I have no clue what to try.

```
rich=# \c sres
FATAL:  no such database: sres             # Indeed there is though
Previous connection kept
rich=#
```

Updated:  More info ==>

```
rich=# \l
                                List of databases
     Name     | Owner | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | Access privileges
--------------+-------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------
 postgres     | rich  | UTF8     | C           | C           |
 rich         | rich  | UTF8     | C           | C           |
 sres         | rich  | UTF8     | C           | C           |
 sresearch    | rich  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 template0    | rich  | UTF8     | C           | C           | =c/rich          +
              |       |          |             |             | rich=CTc/rich
 template1    | rich  | UTF8     | C           | C           | =c/rich          +
              |       |          |             |             | rich=CTc/rich
(6 rows)

rich=# \c sres;
FATAL:  no such database: sres
Previous connection kept
rich=# \s sresearch;
Wrote history to file "sresearch".
rich=#
```

Here is the feedback from `Sequel`:

[image: Commands from Ruby]

[image: Here are the results from Ruby]

[image]

Updated.  Even more of the same.  ==>

```
rich=# CREATE DATABASE alpha;
CREATE DATABASE
rich=# \c alpha;
FATAL:  no such database: alpha
Previous connection kept
rich=# \l
                                List of databases
     Name     | Owner | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | Access privileges
--------------+-------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------
 alpha        | rich  | UTF8     | C           | C           |
 postgres     | rich  | UTF8     | C           | C           |
 rich         | rich  | UTF8     | C           | C           |
 template0    | rich  | UTF8     | C           | C           | =c/rich          +
              |       |          |             |             | rich=CTc/rich
 template1    | rich  | UTF8     | C           | C           | =c/rich          +
              |       |          |             |             | rich=CTc/rich
(5 rows)

rich=# DROP DATABASE alpha;
DROP DATABASE
rich=# \l
                                List of databases
     Name     | Owner | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | Access privileges
--------------+-------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------
 postgres     | rich  | UTF8     | C           | C           |
 rich         | rich  | UTF8     | C           | C           |
 template0    | rich  | UTF8     | C           | C           | =c/rich          +
              |       |          |             |             | rich=CTc/rich
 template1    | rich  | UTF8     | C           | C           | =c/rich          +
              |       |          |             |             | rich=CTc/rich
(4 rows)

rich=# CREATE DATABASE alpha;
CREATE DATABASE
rich=# \l
                                List of databases
     Name     | Owner | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | Access privileges
--------------+-------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------
 alpha        | rich  | UTF8     | C           | C           |
 postgres     | rich  | UTF8     | C           | C           |
 rich         | rich  | UTF8     | C           | C           |
 template0    | rich  | UTF8     | C           | C           | =c/rich          +
              |       |          |             |             | rich=CTc/rich
 template1    | rich  | UTF8     | C           | C           | =c/rich          +
              |       |          |             |             | rich=CTc/rich
(5 rows)

rich=# \c alpha;
FATAL:  no such database: alpha
Previous connection kept
rich=#
```

Comment: [In psql, why do some commands have no effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472026) - TL/TR: end your statements with  `;`

Comment: Like I said, a third party client also has the same problem.  As well as an `ORM` cannot so this.

Comment: What you have shown in your question,  the lack of a `;` is clearly the reason why the database wasn't created. And no, `psql` did **not** report having done so, because it would have shown `CREATE DATABASE` as a success message before returning to the prompt.

Comment: All those errors in the screenshots stem from the fact that your initial `create database sresearch` did no do anything because you forgot the `;`

Comment: Third party client and `Sequel` both write proper syntax aside `psql`.  This error is showing up in all three ways to create a new database.  I've posted more trials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit was `pgbouncer` and the `.ini` file, which needs individual entries for each listed database.  Creating the database was ok, but then the `.ini` file didn't recognize the new database name.